# Is this language recognizable or unrecognizable

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, turing-recognizable

Let L = { y = {0,1}* | y = code(M) for some Turing Machine M and M halts on no input}

How can I prove whether this language recognizable or unrecognizable?

Comment: We're not looking for posts that consist solely of the text of an exercise-style task.  What are your thoughts?  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @D.W. this is definitely not a home work question but thank you for your comment. I modified the question as well. I am interested in the process of creating such proof.